# how to remove ctrl F in unix file

Tags: sed

While editing a unix file I'm getting data as below in vi editor.

```
MGW:^FVMG107
MGW:^FVMG113
MGW:^FVMG108
MGW:^FVMG103
```

where in above data `^F` is not viewable in `cat` command.
I have tried `dos2unix` & `sed` also, but it still exists. 
How can I remove `^F`

Answer (score 15):

`^F` is vim telling you there is a non-printable character 0x06 there (F is the sixth letter of the alphabet, they range: '^@', '^A', '^B'... '^Y', '^Z'. '^[', '^\', '^]', '^^', '^_')

I had no problem removing it graphically in vim, nano, joe… but if you prefer a command line approach, knowing that it's the character 0x06, you can use `sed -i 's/\x06//g' filename` to remove it.

PS: I'm afraid polym solution of removing ^F on `cat -v` will only work if your file doesn't have any other unprintable characters, which would get mangled.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As [Angel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139934/72471) mentioned, you shouldn't use this solution, since it might  produce undesirable changes.

His solution (hex(`^F`)==`\x06`):

```
sed -i 's/\x06//g' filename
```

My (inproper) solution:

```
cat -v oldfile | sed 's/\^F//g' > newfile
```

should do it.

Comment: As Ángel says below, this will potentially make other undesirable changes to the contents of the file - it's not a very general answer to the question.

Comment: In addition to Ángel’s comment (referring to the functionality of `cat -v`), this will also cause corruption if the file happens to have any `^` characters that are immediately followed by `F` characters.

Comment: @godlygeek and Scott thanks for the info :)!

Answer (score 2):

As Ángel says, `^F` in `vi` or the output of `cat -v` denotes an 06 character. 
Another way of getting rid of these characters is

```
tr -d "\06" < oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're working with the file in vim, you can fix this within vi/vim too. You can type these character with ctrl-v, then ctrl-. For this, it's crtl-v, followed by ctrl-f.

So, you can use a simple find/replace:

```
:%s/^F//
```

That would work on all lines (the %), and replace (the s), the first instance of ^F, with nothing, effectively removing it.

If you want to see hidden characters in files, instead of cat, try using od -c:

```
od -c <file name>
```

eg, but putting a ^F and two line-endings in a file:

```
alex@Smiley:/tmp|⇒  cat test


alex@Smiley:/tmp|⇒  od -c test
0000000  006  \n  \n
0000003
```

This prints out all characters escaped, including tabs, line endings, etc.

If you want to use sed, you can use the same ctrl-V, crtl- trick right on the command-line too. That way you don't need to remember the translation.